# How to connect to localhost postgres database from docker container?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm configured my project to docker. I have database that have been used in non-docker period and now I want to connect my docker-compose db service to it. But when I write `docker-compose up` - existing database not used - new one created instead (I suspect, docker container simply doesn't see the database). If I do nonsense please let me know. Maybe I shoud migrate my server db into container.

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=mydb
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=p@ssw0rd
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      # We'll mount the 'postgres-data' volume into the location Postgres stores it's data:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && ./manage.py migrate && ./run_gunicorn.sh"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - /static:/static
    ports:
      - 443:443
    depends_on:
      - db
  nginx:
    restart: always
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./misc/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - /static:/static
    depends_on:
  - web
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the canonic approach is to have your DB engine running in container while storing the data on the persistent storage (map the volume to your hard disk).
So I would use the Postgres in docker as ServerDB, as you suggested.

Comment: So pretty. And where I'm wrong? Why my db engine do not see my db that storing on the persistent storage. Could you take a look to docker compose config?

Comment: In your docker-compose.yml you're mounting a named data volume, not a folder from the host:https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#data-volumes
Try using a path to the host folder with data instead, i.e. `./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data`

Answer (score 0):

If you only want your application connect to the external database, declare it as an external host:

```
version: '2'
services:

  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && ./manage.py migrate && ./run_gunicorn.sh"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - /static:/static
    ports:
      - 443:443
    extra_hosts:
      - "db:192.168.1.2"

  nginx:
    restart: always
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./misc/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - /static:/static
    depends_on:
      - web
```

Just be sure your application reference the database as db and replace the ip I put there with your host ip.

Regards